# Jerky scrolling with only a few images

Tags: iphone, uitableview, scroll

I'm using the method that Apple shows on using subviews in table (most of what is below is from their documentation).  I am only pulling in via an rss feed about 12 images, but this results in slow scrolling - if I get rid of the images it moves smoothly.  The images are not big, so that can't be the problem.  Before looking into more involved solutions (background processing, etc.), is there anything I can do to make this work better?

Thanks for any help you can give on this.

```
#define MAINLABEL_TAG   1
#define SECONDLABEL_TAG 2
#define PHOTO_TAG       3

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView : (UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath : (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UILabel * mainLabel, * secondLabel;
    UIImageView * photo;
    static NSString * CellIdentifier = @ "Cell";
    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

        mainLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100.0, 0.0, 210.0, 0.0)] autorelease];
        mainLabel.tag = MAINLABEL_TAG;
        mainLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];
        mainLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
        mainLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        mainLabel.opaque = YES;
        mainLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        [cell.contentView addSubview : mainLabel];

        secondLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(90.0, 30.0, 220.0, 0.0)] autorelease];
        secondLabel.tag = SECONDLABEL_TAG;
        secondLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];
        secondLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
        secondLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
        secondLabel.opaque = YES;
        secondLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        [cell.contentView addSubview : secondLabel];

        photo = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30.0, 3.0, 50.0, 40.0)] autorelease];
        photo.tag = PHOTO_TAG;
        photo.opaque = YES;
        photo.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        [cell.contentView addSubview : photo];
    } else {
        mainLabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag : MAINLABEL_TAG];
        secondLabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag : SECONDLABEL_TAG];
        photo = (UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag : PHOTO_TAG];
    }
    // Configure the cell.
    mainLabel.text = [[items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@ "title"];
    secondLabel.text = [[items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@ "teacher"];
    NSString * path = [[items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@ "audimage"];
    NSString * mypath = [path stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:mypath];
    NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    UIImage * img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
    photo.image = img;
    return cell;
    [cell release];
}
```

Comment: `[cell release];` will never be called, as nothing in a method after return will be reached

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like every time you're configuring a cell, you re-download the entire image from the web (or reading from the hard disk, if that's where your URL points to):

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
```

This is really slow! The way `UITableView` works is by reusing cells - every time a cell goes off-screen, it may be given back to the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method to be used as the next cell that becomes visible.

This means that *every* time a new cell becomes visible, you're downloading and creating its image.

Instead, you have two options:

1. Download and store all the images first (if there are only 12, it probably won't take too much memory).
2. Download the images as-needed, and if you get a memory warning, dump some of the cached images. This is a bit harder to implement, so I'd try the first solution first.

Comment: Hmm..thanks..I was thinking of that..so there is no caching going on with the images such that they stay in memory when the image scrolls off the view?

Comment: @Allen, nope - because that cell that scrolls off the view is then assigned a new image, so it loses its old one.

Comment: oh...so their is now way around this like checking to see if it loses the image, then only then go and get the image again..like if photo,image is nil, get the image again.  Sorry if this doesn't make sense, just trying to find something simple If that's even possible)

Comment: @Allen - the problem is that the same `UITableViewCell` gets used to represent different *actual* cells in your table view. So imagine that you're looking at cells #1,2,3,4,5. Then you scroll #1 off-screen and #6 appears. It will actually be the *same* `UITableViewCell` used for #1 that's reused for #6. So it wouldn't make sense to save the image in the `UITableViewCell`, since it now needs a *different* image!